# NSUserDefaults Arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray

I need two `NSMutableArray` that will contain `NSString`.

These arrays are:

```
ListOFUserNames=[NSMutableArray array];
SituationstoName =[NSMutableArray array];
```

I have two different sets of strings that go into each mutable array.

After named gets added to `Listofusernames`

Situation gets added to `SituationstoName`

```
 [ListOFUserNames addObject:AfterNamed];
 [SituationstoName addObject:Situation];
```

I am trying to save `listofusernames` and `situationstoname` with their respective strings.

```
 NSUserDefaults *something = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];     
 [something setObject:ListOFUserNames forKey:@"somedata"];
 [something synchronize];

 NSUserDefaults *something2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
 [something2 setObject:SituationstoName forKey:@"somedata2"];
 [something2 synchronize];
```

In the method that loads them, nothing comes out.
The code for that method is:

```
NSUserDefaults *somet = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults *somet2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

ListOFUserNames = [somet objectForKey:@"somedata"] ;
SituationstoName = [somet2 objectForKey:@"somedata2"] ;
[somet synchronize];
[somet2 synchronize];
```

The problem is that it is not loading the strings that are saved in the mutable arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//initialise array
NSMutableArray *listOFUserNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *situationstoName =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//add content in the array
[listOFUserNames addObject:AfterNamed];
[situationstoName addObject:Situation];
```

(Before storing also check if your array contains objects or is empty.)

```
//Store these array in `NSUserDefaults`
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:listOFUserNames forKey:@"NameData"];
[userDefaults setObject:situationstoName forKey:@"SituationData"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

//Access data where ever you want to be
//(listOFUserNames and situationstoName must be array)
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
listOFUserNames = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"NameData"] ;
situationstoName = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"SituationData"] ;
```